# Que tipado tendría que ir en las props de mi componente?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy empezando con typescript y me están asaltando algunas dudas para hacer mi código más sólido. Tengo un componente que es un menu con tres opciones:

```
const List = ({ statusEvents }: { statusEvents: any }) => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();

  const handleStatusEvents = (status: string): void => {
    statusEvents(status);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListStyled>
        <li>
          <NavLinkStyled
            activeClassName="link"
            to={`${match.path}/pendientes`}
            onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("pendientes")}
          >
            Pendientes
          </NavLinkStyled>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLinkStyled
            activeClassName="link"
            to={`${match.path}/activas`}
            onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("activas")}
          >
            Activas
          </NavLinkStyled>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLinkStyled
            activeClassName="link"
            to={`${match.path}/resultados`}
            onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("resultados")}
          >
            Resultados
          </NavLinkStyled>
        </li>
      </ListStyled>
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Y su componente padre:

```
interface IPropsState {
  index: number;
  image: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  time: string;
  assistants: number;
  isActive: boolean;
}

const EventPage = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<IPropsState[]>(ListOfEvents);

  const handleChangeStatusEvents = (status: string) => {
    switch (status) {
      case "pendientes":
        const pendientes = ListOfEvents.filter(
          (event) => event.isActive === false
        );
        setFilter(pendientes);
        break;
      case "activas":
        const activas = ListOfEvents.filter((event) => event.isActive === true);
        setFilter(activas);
        break;
      case "resultados":
        const resultados = ListOfEvents;
        setFilter(resultados);
    }
  };

  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Spacer height="30" />
      <Title text="Eventos" />
      <Spacer height="30" />
      <List statusEvents={handleChangeStatusEvents} />
      {filter ? <ListEvents events={filter} /> : <EmptyEvents />}
    </MainLayout>
  );
};

export default EventPage;
```

En este menú lo que hace es enviar a través del onClick a una función ***handleStatusEvents*** a su componente antecesor pasando por props un texto con el nombre de cada categoría.

```
onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("pendientes")}



 const handleStatusEvents = (status: string): void => {
    statusEvents(status);
  };
```

El tipado de la función ***handleStatusEvents*** es de tipo void y los argumentos son de tipo string. Cuando quiero pasarle el statusEvents a su padre (por props)

```
const List = ({ statusEvents }: { statusEvents: any }) => {}
```

tengo que poner :any porque en el componente padre, la prop ***statusEvents*** está llamando a una función que setea los states. Entonces es aquí que clase de tipado tengo que ponerle (que no sea any), porque por una parte entiendo que desde el componente hijo está "saliendo" un string por props, pero el padre está llamando una función... No entiendo muy bien que tipado sería el deseado. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TypeScript Interface y Function type expression

Una interface `TypeScript` sirve para definir la forma de las propiedades de un objeto, en este caso del componente ReactJS.

Ahora, se puede usar la forma `function type expression with parameter` para describir el método `handleChangeStatusEvents`, junto con una `interface`:

```
interface Props {
    statusEvents: (a:string) => void;
}
```

De acuerdo a la [documentacion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) de `TS` la siguiente línea:

```
(a:string) => void
```

Se puede interpretar como:

> Una función con un parámetro, llamado a, de tipo cadena, que no tiene un valor de retorno.

El método `handleChangeStatusEvents` no tiene un `return` explícito, por lo que se puede configurar en `TypeScript` como una función que regresa `void` y además, espera recibir un parametro de tipo `string`.

Luego, se configura el componente ReactJS para recibir la interface `Props`:

```
const List = ({ statusEvents }: Props) => {
//return...
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Ya no da ningún error de tipado. Muchas gracias! g.4

Comment: Se ve muy bien tu proyecto colega, por cierto ¿Los componentes como `NavLinkStyled` los estas sacando de alguna librería o tu los estas construyendo? saludos

Comment: Hola @g.4! `NavLinkStyled` es un componente creado con styled components. Saludos!